# Prisma datamodel.prisma gives several errors on model

Tags: graphql, datamodel, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm learning to work with GraphQl and prisma and I'm following this tutorial --> https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/4-adding-a-database/

I've followed it but changed the Link to a Service that has a name field and a cost(for now this is a string) and I made a datamodel.prisma file that looks like this

```
type Service {
    id: ID! @id
    createdAt: DataTime! @createdAt
    updatedAt: DataTime! @updatedAt
    name: String!
    cost: String!
}
```

but it gives me this errors which don't understand it should be the right syntax?:

```
Errors:

  Service
    × The field `createdAt` has the type `DataTime!` but there's no type or enum declaration with that name.
    × The field `updatedAt` has the type `DataTime!` but there's no type or enum declaration with that name.
    × The relation field `createdAt` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`
    × The relation field `updatedAt` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`
    × Fields that are marked as `@createdAt` must be of type `DateTime!` or `DateTime`.    
    × Fields that are marked as @updatedAt must be of type `DateTime!` or `DateTime`.
```

I'm not sure why my datamodel is providing these errors could anyone help me with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo -- it's `DateTime`, not `DataTime`.

Comment: Yes, I was so sure that I wrote everything the right way but you are right! Stupid mistake

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with prisma when i use npx prisma migrate dev.

i have this error for each datetime i use  :

```
error: Type "Datetime" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another 
model, custom type, or enum.
schema.prisma: 
14 | id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
15 | createdAt Datetime @default(now())
```

i learn nestJS with prisma and docker.

```
model User {
id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
createdAt Datetime @default(now())
updatedAt Datetime @updatedAt

email String @unique
hash String
role Role @default(USER)

firstName String? 
lastName String?
}

model Bookmark {
id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
createdAt Datetime @default(now())
updatedAt Datetime @updatedAt

title String
description String?
link String
}
```

Comment: `Datetime` should be `DateTime` (notice the second capital `T`). Docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#datetime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky thanks all works fine now, i don't think this detail can broke the build.

Comment: @Skyjox Prisma is case-sensitive, so you have to spell it as `DateTime`. `Datetime` will cause the Prisma schema to fail during compilation.

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky yep thanks for explication and your time